# Can I do an async XML call in Excel 2010 VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, msxml

In my spreadsheet I have a reference to the MS XML v3 library.

Here is my sample code

```
Option Explicit


Private objConn As XMLHTTP30


Public Sub HandleAsyncEvent()
    Debug.Print "Done"
End Sub

Public Function InitService(serviceUrl As String, Optional asyncMode As Boolean = True)
    Set objConn = New XMLHTTP30
    objConn.Open "POST", serviceUrl, asyncMode
    objConn.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    objConn.onreadystatechange = HandleAsyncEvent

End Function
```

I encountered a runtime exception when it comes to the line

```
objConn.onreadystatechange = HandleAsyncEvent
```

Excel throws the exception "Object required"

Is it actually possible to pass a function into `onreadystatechange` here? Can I pass a function "pointer" around in excel vba?

Comment: Here's an approach to this type of task: http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/

Comment: @Tim Look like it is an answer to my question. You can make it an answer so I can upvote and tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach to this type of task:

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/